# Visual Studio Go to All open files from bin and obj folder even I exclude them in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I have a WPF project which is working fine, The problem I have seen with Visual Studio is it keeps showing me files from bin and obj folder. I exclude them and unselect the show all file in Visual Studio Solution Explorer.

I keep seeing this when I type CTRL +, Is there a way to stop seeing this thing in "Go to All" or Is this a bug in Visual Studio 2017.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't have the obj and bin folders in Solution Explorer. Get rid of them, you build them with the code.

I don't think it's a bug. Remove these artifacts.

One way to get into this is when adding files to Source Control, did you see a Prompt to include all the *.obj, *.pdb, etc files?

You will have to unbind the solution from Source Control, and in a new repository add all the source control files (excluding bin, obj folders and non-source code files).

Comment: I have no control over the repository, I did remove both folders from the repository and we start getting the issue like we need that dll that only I have. Is there any other way to get it sort out the other way.

Comment: Change the Projects to reference each other via a project reference not a DLL path. If you have 3rd party DLLs that your code doesn't build put them in the repository and reference them by relative DLL path.